# Binding from itemscontrol to usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls, itemscontrol

I have a usercontrol called `MessageElementControl`. it is contained by a `MessageElementContainerControl`. when I call the `MessageElementControl`, I am trying to pass to it some properties from the container but those properties are not being set. when I try to use them inside the `MessageElementControl` they are null. the problematic properties are `ParentCollection` and `ParentObject`. I do this so that when a user does something to the `MessageElementControl` like update or delete I can make the necessary changes to the collection. here is the XAML for the container. the question is how do I make those properties get the correct value? or if I should take a completely different approach to the whole thing?

```
<UserControl x:Class="Bix.MessageElementContainerControl" Loaded="ThisControl_Loaded"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="ThisControl" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Bix" 
             >
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MessageElementDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type my:MessageElementDataProvider}"/>

        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MessageUIElements"
          ObjectInstance="{StaticResource MessageElementDataProvider}"
          MethodName="GetUIMessageElements"/>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MessageElement">
            <my:MessageElementControl Width="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl,Path=Width}" 
                                          Element="{Binding Path=Element}" 
                                          ParentCollection="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl,Path=ItemsSource}" 
                                          ParentObject="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl,Path=ParentObjectSource}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel Height="Auto" Name="panel1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" Name="panel2">
            <Label Content="Attachments and Data" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF5A5A5A" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="label6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl,Path=LabelWidth}" />
            <Button Margin="0,4" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="btnNew" Padding="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Click="btnNew_Click">
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF3C3C3C" Text="New" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl,Path=Width}">
            <ItemsControl Name="itmsElements" Margin="0" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MessageUIElements}}" 
                          Width="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl,Path=Width}"
                          ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource MessageElement}}">

            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

UPDATE: found it.  i was using ThisControl as the name for the Container and the contained. so binding wasn't really happening. found a useful post about debugging wpf bindings that helped me figure it out. [devcomponents.com/blog/?p=312](http://devcomponents.com/blog/?p=312)

Comment: Try binding the `ItemsControl.ItemSource` to `ObservableCollection` in your view model. Every change in the collection will update the control immediately.

Comment: It is an observable.. that's a whole other issue. I am using observables all over the place and the itemscontrol doesn't seem to care when i make changes to the source collection. i need to reset ItemsSource to make it refresh the UI. but the issue on this question was caused by conflicting usercontrol names. i was using ThisControl as the name for the Container and the contained. found a useful post about debugging wpf bindings that helped me figure it out. http://devcomponents.com/blog/?p=312

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that the way to go would be to bind your collection container to an `ObservableCollection` (`MessageUIElements`) of `MessageElement`, your selected item to a property of the `MessageElement` type all in a class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in case you wish to drive the selected item from the code.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that's the architecture i have.. but for some reason the ItemsControl doesn't respond to it.